# Calling QueryAsync in Dapper throws a InvalidOperationException

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await, dapper

I was trying out the async support in dapper and when running a simple use case I ran into the follow issue. I have an ApiController that just triggers a log entries using dapper to create it in the database. My db connections are fine. When I run a synchronous version of the using the Query extension method from dapper, everything works fine. When I use the QueryAsync along with the async/await constructs, I get an InvalidOperationException. Here's what the code looks like

```
public class BackgroundController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(string op)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Backgrounder"].ConnectionString))
        {
            const string sql =
                "Insert Into SimpleLog (message, threadid, created) Values(@message, @threadid, @created); " +
                "SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)";
            var results = await (connection.QueryAsync<int>(sql, new { message = "new log record", threadid = "1", created = DateTime.Now }));
            var id = results.SingleOrDefault();
            Debug.WriteLine("inserted log record id: " + id);
        }
        return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Also, here is what the stacktrace look like:

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.b_*24(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Dapper.SqlMapper.<QueryAsync>d__69`1.MoveNext() in c:\Dev\Dapper\Dapper NET45\SqlMapperAsync.cs:line 21
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at WebApiBackgrounder.Controllers.BackgroundController.d*_0.MoveNext()

It seems to be failing when dapper makes a call to ExecuteReaderAsync. Does anyone how to address this?

**EDIT**

Here's the connection string

```
 <add name="Backgrounder" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=LPW7X6530;Initial Catalog=Sandbox;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
```

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: Does your connection string include `Asynchronous Processing=True` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I didn't before, but adding it doesn't prevent the exception either

Comment: @svick the message is "Invalid operation. The connection is closed."

Comment: @cecilphillip does it work if you open the connection first?

Comment: @MarcGravell yep. That works. Thanks!! Please add the answer so I can make this as solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like the connection is not open. As it happens, dapper normally tries to do this for you - so it is not unreasonable that you didn't call Open() first - I guess we missed that. For now: call Open() on the connection.

Comment: added this be added in a future release?

Comment: await connection.OpenAsync();

They must be using the async fork of Dapper

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper-Async/